# Get and set cookies in rvest

Tags: r, cookies, web-scraping, rvest, httr

How can I check my session cookies and specify those cookies before making a subsequent web request?

I want to scrape a page but I cannot submit the cookies.

I'm using the rvest library.

My code:

```
library(rvest)
WP <- html_session("http://www.wp.pl/")
headers <- httr::headers(WP)
cookies <- unlist(headers[names(headers) == "set-cookie"])
crumbs <- stringr::str_split_fixed(cookies, "; ", 4)
# method 1
stringr::str_split_fixed(crumbs[, 1], "=", 2)
# method 2
cookies(WP)
```

How do I set my cookies to do the web scraping?

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep in mind that [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf) is built on top of the [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) library.
2. For some reason that I can't explain, this code didn't work [until I rebooted RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441865/how-to-properly-set-cookies-to-get-url-content-using-httr#comment86192045_26442118).

---

[Here's some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26442118/109941) that'll do the trick:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

httr::GET("http://www.wp.pl/", 
    set_cookies(`_SMIDA` = "7cf9ea4bfadb60bbd0950e2f8f4c279d",
                `__utma` = "29983421.138599299.1413649536.1413649536.1413649536.1",
                `__utmb` = "29983421.5.10.1413649536",
                `__utmc` = "29983421",
                `__utmt` = "1",
                `__utmz` = "29983421.1413649536.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)")) %>%
    read_html %>%  # Sample rvest code
    read_table(fill=TRUE) # Sample rvest code
```