# How to extract all cookies from Selenium (RSelenium) session and use them in GET request (httr)

Tags: cookies, get, httr, rselenium

Using

```
cookies <- remDr$getAllCookies()
```

I am able to extract cookies from my RSelenium session.

They look something like this:

[image]

I can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441865/how-to-properly-set-cookies-to-get-url-content-using-httr) that it is possible to manually define cookie name and values.

However, I am unsure which specific cookie is critical to my needs and so I would like to input all of these cookies into my GET request.

How can this be done programmatically? I.e., transforming the `cookies` "list of 33" into an input argument for the GET request?

[image]

In an ideal world, it would look something like this:

```
cookies <- remDr$getAllCookies()
get_dm_location <- GET("https://api.xxxxxx.com/apis/ui/Products/117885",
                       set_cookies(cookies))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cookies is a named list then simply call unlist() to generate the required named character vector

```
set_cookies(cookies %>% unlist())
```